# Batman TAS - Mudslide - Why didn't Batman let Clayface to turn back to normal

Tags: dc, batman, dc-animated-universe, batman-the-animated-series

In Batman TAS episode *Mudslide* from the second season, Clayface is stealing money and chemicals so he can be turned back to a normal human being, since he has problems holding himself together at the molecular level.

Batman chases him and offers him a cure and Clayface refuses it. Later in the episode Batman stops the procedure that was already turning Clayface back to normal. Why would Batman do this? He wanted to cure Clayface and he definitely could arrest him more easily if he were a normal person.

Comment: Because he's Batman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing the episode, I have three theories:

### Crime Cannot Pay

Batman is a firm believer in moving within the limits of the law. He repeatedly offered Clayface a chance to have a lawful cure, and could not countenance the cure being done with stolen materials and kidnapped doctors. It was the method, not the cure, that he opposed.

### The "cure" was untested

The FDA clamps down on people preaching wonder cures involving everything from injected stem cells to lethal doses of belladonna to bleach enemas. They do this because these "cures" typically involve a small sample size and erasure of the failure cases to make results look more impressive. There was no guarantee that this would have actually worked for Clayface. In fact, the fact that Clayface seemed to be falling apart even faster after the partial injection suggests that it might have "fixed" him in the same way that methamphetamine "gives you more energy", namely that it overcharges the system, giving him temporary control, but ultimately leaves him more damaged. In a more clinical setting, this effect might be better controlled.

### It would not have made him "normal"

Lastly, addressing your point about it being easier to capture Clayface without his powers... what makes you think it would make his powers go away? All that is shown was that it allowed him to hold a human form longer. Odds are, he still would have had all of his prior powers, just with more power and control, something which would not make him easier to catch, and would not fix his base psychosis.

Comment: I would argue about the first theory since I can't see that much of a difference between healing someone who did horrific crimes and letting the same person heal himself by stolen goods. The second theory seems the most plausible to me and your point about Clayface not losing his powers is a good one, I didn't realize that. Thanks for explaining :)